# Retaining the $_POST values in dynamically added fields

Tags: javascript, php, html

An array is created from my dynamically added input fields, I want to retain the values in the input fields, once the user clicks on the button.

If I use `if(isset($_POST['creategroup'])) echo $_POST['creategroup'];` it would display the whole array. I want the values to be displayed separately in their respective input fields. Is there any good solution to it?

My Html code is:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-6">
        <input class="form-control" placeholder="Enter Group Name" type="text" name="group" required></input>
    </div>
</div>    

<div class="row">
    <br />
    <div class="col-xs-6">
        <input class="form-control" placeholder="Enter email address" type="email" name="email[]" value="" required></input>
    </div>
</div>    
</div>
```

Script is:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var max_fields      = 10; //maximum input boxes allowed
    var wrapper         = $("#input_fields_wrap"); //Fields wrapper
    var add_button      = $("#add_field_button"); //Add button ID

    var x = 1; //initlal text box count
    $(add_button).click(function(e){ //on add input button click
        e.preventDefault();
        if(x < max_fields){ //max input box allowed
            x++; //text box increment
            $(wrapper).append('<div class="row"><div class="col-xs-6" style="margin-top:0.2cm;"><input type="email" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter another email address" name="email[]" required><a href="#" id="remove_field"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-minus"></span></a></div></div>'); //add input box

        }
    });

    $(wrapper).on("click","#remove_field", function(e){ //user click on remove text
        e.preventDefault(); $(this).parent('div').remove(); x--;
    })
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question missing your PHP Part.
Generally if you have defined array names in the form input name with for example `email[]` than this is available in PHP with `$_POST["email"][0]`. 
No index means (with `[]`) automatically counting up the index number for each input field with that name.
You can manually define the index name with for example `email[foo]` than it is available in PHP with `$_POST["email"]["foo"]`.
With that information you should be able to make it working.